# avoid dead locks in recursive web calls on rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, webserver

let's say I've sent a get request to some action in some controller in rails.

and in that action I'm sending requests to get web pages from another server. 
for example :

`open("http://example.com/myexample.xml")`

when i call this function using `localhost` as a parameter the site requests it self so the server goes in a dead lock state and stops

any ideas to get page of `localhost` without making the requests queued on the main thread ?

the same problem happens when the main thread sleeps or get busy to process a request  and another request comes to the server ... it waits till the first request is finished.

any solutions for that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can run another server instance:

```
rails s          # http://localhost:3000
rails s -p 3001  # http://localhost:3001
```

Then you can send requests from localhost:3001 to localhost:3000 or on the contrary.

I prefer to use `unicorn` as second server

```
rails s          # http://localhost:3000
unicorn          # http://localhost:8080
```

Comment: what is unicorn ?

the same instance on another port?

Comment: It is just another web server. You can use it to run your application. https://github.com/defunkt/unicorn

Comment: I am not sure of that, but you can try to run just one unicorn server (without rails s) and it might let you to send requests to itself without going in a dead lock